# Javascript checkbox validation: how to alert if user didn't check a particular checkbox?

Tags: javascript, function, cordova, validation, phonegap-build

So what I am doing is something like a simple medication reminder, so the system display a list of medications the user should be taking, and the user then tick the checkbox of the medicine they have taken, but what I want to do is if for example, the user only ticked Medicine One and Two, then I want an alert saying "Why you didn't take Medicine Three?" and a drop down box appears with a list of possible reasons of which the user can choose from. And if the user only took Medicine Three, the system will display alert saying "Why didn't you taken Medicine One and Two?", and drop down box appears with a list of possible reasons. And if user has ticked all three checkbox, then display an alert saying "That great! Well Done!"

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="one">Medicine One<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="b" value="two">Medicine Two<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="c" value="three">Medicine Three<br>
<input id=xbutton type="button" onClick="validate()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I know how to do validation for one checkbox (like a terms agreement checkbox), but I'm a bit confused as to how to incorporate so many validation rules into one function.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to iterate all the `checkbox` elements and check the `.checked` property.

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

`input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)` will select only those elements which are not `checked`.

```js
function validate() {
  var msg = [];
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)'), function(elem, index) {
    msg.push(elem.name);
  });
  alert(msg.length ? 'Please check ' + msg.join(' and ') : 'All are checked!');
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="one">Medicine One
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="two">Medicine Two
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="three">Medicine Three
  <br>
  <input id=xbutton type="button" onClick="validate()" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/5109Lzjd/1/)

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to put both alert into same alert box? Like instead of displaying two alert box (one for not taking medicine one, another one for not taking medicine two), can one alert box display "Why you didn't take medicine one and medicine two?"

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery can help you to make things easy.

**Here is the fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/zs7tpuo0/

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="a" value="one">Medicine One<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="two">Medicine Two<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="c" value="three">Medicine Three<br>
    <input id=xbutton type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
$("#xbutton").click(function(){
    validate();
});

function validate(){
    if ( $('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length == 3 ) {
    alert("Select atleast one option.");
  }
}
```